# how to dynamically add a value in react-native-html-to-pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, html-to-pdf

I am trying to take an Input from the user and and then save it as a pdf file but in the example there isn't any way shown on how to add a dynamic value in the pdf
here is the example

```
async createPDF() {
    let options = {
      html: '<h1>PDF TEST</h1>',
      fileName: 'test',
      directory: 'Documents',
    };

    let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options)
    // console.log(file.filePath);
    alert(file.filePath);

  }
```

and I am trying to do some thing like this

```
async createPDF() {
    let options = {
      html: '<h1>PDF {this.state.value}</h1>',
      fileName: 'test',
      directory: 'Documents',
    };

    let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options)
    // console.log(file.filePath);
    alert(file.filePath);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
async createPDF() {
    let options = {
      html: `<h1>PDF ${this.state.value}</h1>`,
      fileName: 'test',
      directory: 'Documents',
    };

    let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options)
    // console.log(file.filePath);
    alert(file.filePath);
  }
```

Note that this assumes that `this.state` is available to the function scope

Answer (score -1):

You could probably add a setter function that dynamically creates your html then set it as a string.